# Submodular Monimization with Cardinality Constraint

Tags: modular-forms

I am new to submodular functions and I am reading the *introductions to submodular functions and applications* ( https://www.ima.umn.edu/optimization/seminar/queyranne.pdf ).

In this introduction, it says

*"
A submodular set function can be minimized in strongly polynomial time.
Remark: • minimizing a submodular function f, subject to a cardinality constraint, such as |A| = b, or |A| ≥ b, or |A| ≤ b are NP-hard when f is a cut function
".*

In the remark, it says the problem is NP-hard if 1) there is a cardinality constraint and 2) *f* is a cut function.

What if only one of the 2 constraints holds, i.e. *f* is not a cut function but there is a cardinality constraint? Is this problem of minimizing *f(A)* still an NP-hard problem?

Comment: Cross-posted to cstheory: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/30760/hardness-of-minimizing-submodular-functions-with-cardinality-constraints  (please don't simultaneously cross-post, it can waste people's time/effort)

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with modular forms in the sense intended by the tag (did you look at the tag definition)? I removed the tag.

Comment: Thanks @usul for reminding. I'm new to the forum and didn't really know where to post a question properly. Lesson learned and thanks again.